# how to get value of each indiviual message using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to create a favorite button, that when clicked will favorite the message without reload. everything is coded correctly, except i am having trouble figuring out how i will send each message's individual ID to the ajax response.

my ajax:

```
   $(document).on('submit', '.favourite-form', function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = $(this).serialize();  
   $.ajax({ 
  data: data, 
  type: "post", 
   url: "favorite.php?message=529", // here i put 529 as an example, 
  i need it to be a variable that changes based on which message has been clicked.
  success: function(data) { 
  alert("Data Save: " + data); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) //gracefully handle any errors in the UI
    {
   alert("An ajax error occurred: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
  }
}); 
 });
```

my HTML.

```
   <form class="favourite-form" method="post">
        
        <a class="msg-icon " href="<?php echo "reply?message=" . $row['msgid'] . ""; ?>"></a>
       <button type="submit" name="fav" value="<?php echo $row['msgid'] ?>" ></button>
        </form>
```

My php relies on the id of messages to be sent via $_GET METHOD.

my php :

```
        $user_id = $_SESSION['active_user_id'];
        
    
            extract($_GET);
            $id=$_GET['message'];
            
            $q=$db->prepare("SELECT msgid,date,text
            
            FROM messages 
            WHERE to_id=? and msgid=?");
            $q->bindValue(1,$user_id);
            $q->bindValue(2,$id);
            $q->execute();
            $row2=$q->fetch();
            $d=$row2['date'];
            
            
            $fav_questionq=$db->prepare("SELECT *
            FROM messages
            LEFT JOIN users
            ON messages.to_id=users.id
            WHERE users.id=? AND messages.msgid=?
            
            ");
            $fav_questionq->bindValue(1,$user_id);
            $fav_questionq->bindValue(2,$id);
            $fav_questionq->execute();
            $frow=$fav_questionq->fetch();
            
            $fquestion= $frow['text'];
        
            
            $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM fav_messages
                                WHERE username=? AND message=?");
            $result->bindValue(1,$user_id); 
            $result->bindValue(2,$id);              
            $result->execute();
                                
                        
        if($result->rowCount()== 1 )
        {
            $deletequery=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM fav_messages WHERE message=?");
            $deletequery->bindValue(1,$id);
            $deletequery->execute();
        
        }
        else
        {
        $insertquery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO fav_messages (username,message,fav_question,fav_date) values(?,?,?,?)");
        $insertquery->bindValue(1,$user_id);
        $insertquery->bindValue(2,$id);
        $insertquery->bindValue(3,$fquestion);
        $insertquery->bindValue(4,$d);
        $insertquery->execute();
        }
        
        
        
        ?>
```

how can i send each message id via ajax this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.favourite-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    // Here, you will get the individual id before submiting the form
    var mssg_id = $(this).find('button[name="fav"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        url: `favorite.php?message=${mssg_id}`, // It will be added to the url ES6 method
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data Save: " + data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            alert("An ajax error occurred: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

#### Edit

```
url: "favourite.php?message="+mssg_id,
```

Comment: this is a very close to the answer, but the way you're writing the url is causing and error, the value being passed is this " https://localhost//favorite.php?message=${mssg_id}", also it is still not finding the value of the button.

Comment: I ve eddited. Plz check

Comment: i tried, but still i am getting undefined value. your way seems correct but it is still not getting the value of the button. @

Comment: its working now, thank you so much, you helped me fix the issue!!!

Comment: i had <input > and not <button> i changed and it works, now only one issue occurs, for the first instance of my messages, the value is undefined but, for the other messages all are working fine. find my attached images

Comment: Now you have got your problem solved.. You will get that error by urself... just gotta look closer!!! Best of luck buddy.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is just to add a `hidden input` in the form of the view, try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="msgid" value="<?php echo $row['msgid' ?>" />
```